# How to solve this case with date?

Tags: java

I developing netbeans 8. And insert data error with date.

I have date values in jtable. I try to insert with for loop the row in jtable and the DATE values in it format in dd-MM-yyyy.

```
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < tbcustomer.getRowCount(); i++) {                
            dateformater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            sql = "insert into tbcustomerdetail values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, textid.getText());
            pst.setString(2, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            pst.setString(3, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            pst.setString(4, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
            pst.setString(6, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
            pst.setString(7, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());

            //Test case 1
            //                pst.setString(5, dateformater.format(tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 4)));

            //try secode case

           //                String date=tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
           //                Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
           //                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, date1);
           //                pst.setString(5, dateformater.format(date1));


            pst.setString(8, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());
            pst.setString(9, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());
            pst.setInt(10, 1);
            pst.execute();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error with this line

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Big thank you.

Comment: Again, I using SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: obth code above giving the same error.

Comment: In my SM SQL I gave datatype only date

Comment: tbcustomer is the jtable and I need the value from row i and column 4.

Comment: at row i and column 4 is my date values formate dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: Add that information to your question now.

Comment: you should save `Date` in the table, would make everything easier... and posting the error also helps solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Possibly better is to do the conversion to date as already done in code and then use the setDate method

```
String date = tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
pst.setDate(5, date1);
```

---

Do the conversion in sql instead

```
sql = "insert into tbcustomerdetail values(?,?,?,?, CONVERT(DATE, ?, 105),?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and send the date string exactly as you get it

```
pst.setString(5, tbcustomer.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
```

Comment: better just give `Date` to the `PreparedStatement`, let the driver deal with it

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger You're right, I thought that was what OP did in the code but I see I misread it.

Comment: Thank you @Joakim Danielson, and all I completed with this CONVERT(DATE, ?, 105) with SQL statement

Comment: I have no idea if the OP did  it or not, there is no way to know which data type is in the table model.... probably to late to teach the proper way to do it